# Django - How to show image, after uploading file (.jpg) directly to MEDIA_URL folder

Tags: django, image, media

just to clarify my question:

Let say I have a csv file to upload my list of products to the database. How I can tell Django to look at the MEDIA_URL folder. If the name of the image file is equal to the product name, then use that image file for the product.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why would Django look into MEDIA_URL folder? image locations are normally stored in database. You can write your own code to read folder content if required

Comment: Sorry, I am not that good at Django. And totally forgot that I can upload the image path to the database directly. My bad

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add the media urls into your urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() + static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    )
```

After you have done this, you should be able to display your image this way:

```
<img src="{{ name_of_your_object.name_of_image_field.url }}" alt="your_alt">
```

Also, the view has to return render with context which contains your object:

```
def your_view(request: HttpRequest) -> render:
    """
    Processing GET request

    :param request: HttpRequest
    :returns: render
    """

    context = {}

    context['name_of_your_object'] = NameOfYourObject.object.get(id=id_of_object)

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Hope you find it helpful